# Boost one value of several on field with Spring Data Solr

Tags: java, spring, search, solr4, spring-data-solr

I have a solr field `visibility` that has a set of possible values and I would like to perform a search using Spring Data Solr. I'd like to use `in()` and boost some but not all values if possible.

Here's an example of the search I need,

`visibility:(visible^1000 archived)`

or

`visibility:(visible^1000 draft^500 archived)`

Would this be possible in version 1.0.0.RELEASE or later versions? Currently I'm using 1.0.0.RELEASE.

Thanks, /w

Comment: Or something like `otherfield:value AND (visibility:visible^1000 OR visibility:draft^500 OR visibility:archived)` would work. Not sure how to construct a grouped query like that in spring-data-solr.

Comment: Now that I think of it, an alternate title for this question could be nested query with spring data solr.

Comment: I was able to make this work by using `expression()` like this: `new Criteria("visibility").expression(" (visibility:(visible^1000) OR visibility:(draft^500) OR visibility:(archived)) ")` Doesn't seem right, but works - produces this: `visibility: (visibility:(visible^1000) OR visibility:(draft^500) OR visibility:(archived)) ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never managed to chain this query properly, but was enlightened by petrikainulainen.net on `SimpleStringCriteria()`.

```
Criteria criteria = new SimpleStringCriteria("(visibility:(visible^1000) OR visibility:(draft^500) OR visibility:(archived))");
```

Answer (score 2):

By doing as shown below you will give far higher boost to the docs that has the category as 'webpage'. Then add 'combined' criteria to your existing other criteria

```
Criteria webpage= new Criteria("category" ).is("webpage" ).boost((float) 1000);
Criteria document= new Criteria("category" ).is("document" ).boost((float) 2);
Criteria combined= webpage.or( document);
```